# Laravel on Ubuntu and php7.4 I can see only page with files and folders

Tags: php, laravel, apache2, ubuntu-16.04

On Ubuntu I've installed Laravel and PHP. 
But when I type ip of my server in the browser I can see only files and folders.

**Ubuntu 16.04, php 7.4, apache2**

This is my folder `/var/www/html/myproj/`:

```
root@srv:/var/www/html/myproj# ls
CHANGELOG.md  bpl            laradock      routes      webpack.mix.js
README.md     composer.json  package.json  server.php
app           composer.lock  phpunit.xml   storage
artisan       config         public        tests
bootstrap     database       resources     vendor
```

What I have to do yet?

---

This is laravel.conf file that is in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName yourdomain.tld

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/myproj/public

    <Directory /var/www/html/myproj>
        AllowOverride All
        <RequireAll>
            Require ip 127.0.0.1 xxx.xx.xx.xx
        </RequireAll>
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

---

.htaccess looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: You need to configure the server to point at the `public` directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using Apache2, there are several things to do.
First, try to open the public path in your browser, for example : `http://localhost/public`

If the problem remains, verify in your server configuration that `.htaccess` file are handled, this property must be set in the `apache2` configuration :

```
 AllowOverride All
```

Here is an example with the default web server folder :

```
<Directory /var/www/html/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

In general this value is set to `None` by default, so change it to `All`.

But, to be sure you can do that, you must have activated the `mod_rewrite` extension, so in linux terminal type this :

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: I've added explanations to my post. The result is still the same. I don't know how to modify ./htaccess

Comment: Can you execute the command `dpkg --get-selections | grep php` and tell me if you have a `libapache2-mod-phpXXX` package listed ? (or any package with `apache` and `php` contained in the name)

Comment: Also, just to be sure, execute `sudo a2ensite laravel`. It will ensure that your `laravel.conf` related virtualhost is enabled. Restart your webserver right after that (using `sudo service apache2 restart`).

Comment: root@srv:/var/www/html/myproj# dpkg --get-selections | grep php
dh-php                                          install
libapache2-mod-php                              install
libapache2-mod-php7.0                           install
libapache2-mod-php7.2                           install
libapache2-mod-php7.4                           install

Comment: Hi @Paul, I added above result of your comment

Answer (score 0):

configure the nginx vhost file to point /public folder & also add laravel rewrite rule in vhost file

Answer (score 0):

If you are using nginx try settings below:

```
server {
    listen         80 default_server;
    listen         [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name    example.com www.example.com;
    root           /var/www/html/myproj/public;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm using Apache2